# The database path for Neo4j

Tags: java, database, maven, path, neo4j

I'm less than a beginner in Neo4j.

I've created a Maven project, in which I created the class defined in this link :

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/1.9.5/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java

But I don't know how I can replace the value of the variable **DB_PATH** to make things work :

```
public class EmbeddedNeo4j
{
    private static final String DB_PATH = "target/neo4j-hello-db";
    String greeting;
    // START SNIPPET: vars
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
    Node firstNode;
    Node secondNode;
    Relationship relationship;
    // END SNIPPET: vars

    // other instructions... and methods

}
```

How does the Database look like? Should the path be absolute or relative? a Maven project contains "target" folder, is it the folder they mean?

Can anybody give me a sample about how the database should look like?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually absolute path works best for me, but if know where you're running from, the relative path should also work.

Comment: In my case, I compressed Neo4j .zip in this directory : C:\neo4j-community-1.9.5-windows\neo4j-community-1.9.5 , in which I can find "bin" "data" "conf" and other folders,... is it the path they mean? And how should my database look like? Thank you a lot!

Comment: you want the path to the data/graph.db/ folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest put your database path in any properties file.
e.g.

```
neo4j.db.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/neo4j-community-1.8.2/data/graph.db
```

You can view the database in web admin console.just start your neo4j server and in your browser run `http://127.0.0.1:7474/`

check this link also:::
http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2012/05/23/enabling-neo4j-web-admin-tool-on-the-embedded-server-using-spring-data/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I could find the default database in the browser.

Comment: The default directory : C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb